# How does android source code work?

Tags: android

I have download a set of android source code, which has folders such as "bionic, bootable, build, dalvik, development, frameworks, hadware, packages, prebuilt" and so on. When I browse the whole code, wonder how "import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;" works in Settings.java(D:\android-srce\Google-source\packages\apps\Settings\src\com\android\settings\Settings.java). I guess there is a android.jar file somewhere after compilation. But how does Settings.java import PreferenceActivity correctly?? I'm a beginner in Android, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have downloaded the source code to the Android OS. If you want to build your own ROMS then you need to study about building the OS for a particular hardware platform. This is not trivial.

If you want to build an Android app that runs on an Android device then you want to download the SDK instead - start at [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and follow your nose, buy a book, read the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of information how to change parts of Android. However, you can read information that is connected with the aosp tag. The first cite is [source.android.com](http://source.android.com/) After the installation of android build system you can see video from marakana group. You'll find a lot of valuable information there.

Comment: Yury, thanks. I need learn more before asking such a simple question